# App rejected: 2.23: Apps that spawn processes

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mac-app-store

I uploaded my app to the Mac App Store and it was rejected for the following reason:

```
The app spawns a process that continues running after the user quits the app, without first obtaining user consent. 

The spawned process is /Applications/App.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems?Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Helper
```

Now, obviously my helper app runs in the background, and continues running after the app quits, that's the whole point of it.

The user also has the option to disable the helper app in the preferences.

How can I meet Apple's requirements?

Comment: +1 to counter negative vote - I think its a legitimate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "without the user's consent" part says it all. You should warn the user on first launch (via a dialog), and tell them they can change the setting any time. The dialog should have both "allow background process" and "disallow background process" options. Right now, the user has to figure it out on his own (via Preferences... I guess) and the helper is covertly launched by default; that's the problem I think.

Additionally, you could add the typical "ask me everytime" checkbox at the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: Ok, I figured that would be the problem too.
Thanks!